# regarding java web-services

Tags: web-services

I would like to study WSDL and UDDI. But I am a total noob with web-services. I have good knowledge of servlets and jsps.  Can anybody guide me how to start with web-services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to:

[image]

So one advice: start small, for example with "just" some basic SOAP and WSDL (this is already huge) before to even think of UDDI and other [WS specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Web_service_specifications).

Have a look at the W3Schools [Web Service Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp), check this great [beginner's guide](http://www.predic8.com/wsdl-reading.htm) for WSDL. Then grab a web service stack for your preferred language and start to play with it.

For Java, I'd suggest to use JAX-WS and to start with a Java-first approach (i.e. using annotations). This would hide a lot of the complexity and allow you to get started extremely fast. See [Getting Started with JAX-WS Web Services](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html) for example (NetBeans has very good web services support, I'd recommend it for a beginner).